# prevent access to user profile page from user id

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, user-profile

i have a user profile page that have the following url : www.XXXXXXX.com/userid/45

is there a way to prevent access to other page when a user change /userid/45 to /userid/47

Comment: Need way more info: for starters what language do you use?

Comment: am using php and zend framework

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you're using, something like this on the user profile page:

```
if url_segment(2) != user_info['userid']
  render no_permission
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Zend_Acl.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html

This would allow you to control access to certain resources (e.g. a profile) based upon the assigned privileges of the role making the request.  You can also specify more fine-grained access with assertions.

So, say for example, you specified an 'registered' role, for users registered with your site, who would also have a profile page.  Your rule might read like this :-

'registered' can 'display' a 'profile' 'if it is their profile'.

Role: 'registered'

Privilege: 'display'

Resource: 'profile'

Assertion: code that checks for ownership

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this in wordpress and only after posting my answer did I even realize you were asking about something other than wordpress... Oh well, for people who make my same mistake, here is the same thing, but for wordpress:

You can modify this to make it redirect all users instead of just one user by changing the `==` to `!=` and enter just the admin id (usually "1").

```
add_action('admin_init', 'redirect_to_forum');
function redirect_to_forum(){
    $current_user=wp_get_current_user();

    if($current_user->user_id == "47"){
        header('Location: http://somewhereelse.com');
    }
}
```